# Borel $\sigma$-algebra of initial topology

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a set and $h_i : X \to \mathbb{R}$, $i \in I$ a collection of maps. We can consider on $X$ the initial topology $\tau$ generated by all the $h_i$ and the induced Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\tau)$. We can also consider the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ on $X$ generated by the maps $h_i$.

Under which topological conditions on the space $(X, \tau)$ can we deduce that $\mathcal{B}(\tau) = \Sigma$? I am searching for rather general conditions that can be used for applications. In my situation, I know that $(X,\tau)$ is at least separable and Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if $\mathcal A$ is some collection of subsets of some set then let $\rho(\mathcal A)$ denote the topology and let $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ denote the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal A$

Denote the topology on $\mathbb R$ by $\mathcal V$ so that $\sigma(\mathcal V)$ denotes the Borel $\sigma$ algebra on $\mathbb R$.

Then  $$\mathcal B(\tau)=\sigma(\rho(\bigcup_{i\in I}h_i^{-1}(\mathcal V)))$$
and:$$\Sigma=\sigma(\bigcup_{i\in I}h_i^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal V))$$

It can be shown that $h_i^{-1}(\sigma(\mathcal V))=\sigma(h_i^{-1}(\mathcal V))$ for every $i$ and based on that we find a simpler form for $\Sigma$:$$\Sigma=\sigma(\bigcup_{i\in I}h_i^{-1}(\mathcal V))$$

So it is immediate that $\Sigma\subseteq\mathcal B(\tau)$.

The other inclusion will be valid if and only if:  $$\rho(\bigcup_{i\in I}h_i^{-1}(\mathcal V))\subseteq\sigma(\bigcup_{i\in I}h_i^{-1}(\mathcal V))$$

If $\mathcal W$ denotes a subbase for $\mathcal V$ then $\rho(\bigcup_{i\in I}h_i^{-1}(\mathcal V))=\rho(\bigcup_{i\in I}h_i^{-1}(\mathcal W))$.

We can choose $\mathcal W$ to be countable so if $I$ is countable then in $\bigcup_{i\in I}h_i^{-1}(\mathcal W)$ we have a countable subbase of the topology which on its turn implies a countable base of the topology. That implies that every open set can be written as a countable union of sets in  $\sigma(\bigcup_{i\in I}h_i^{-1}(\mathcal V))$.

So by countable $I$ the equality $\mathcal B(\tau)=\Sigma$ is valid.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't answer the question. At first I thought it was clear that the two algebras are the same just by definition; this is an example showing that they can be different.

Say $X$ is uncountable and let $I=X$. For $x\in X$ let $h_x=\chi_{\{x\}}$.

Then singletons are open in the topology generated by the $h_x$; hence every subset of $X$ is open, so the Borel algebra is the power set of $X$.

Otoh the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the $h_x$ is the minimal $\sigma$-algebra such that every singleton is *measurable*, which is the countable/co-countable algebra.

**Hmm.** The problem with the trivial argument I had in mind showing that the two are equal is that *arbitrary* unions of open sets are open. The two algebras will be equal in any situation where you can show that the *countable* unions of $h_i^{-1}(O)$ ($O$ open) form a topology.